# Unable to connect through Azure Portal

Tags: azure

I've been connecting to Azure through the Portal for a month or two. Today I went to connect and kept getting the following error:

"User account you used to sign in is not supported for this application. Please use a different account to sign in."

I searched for this error and every post I found was related to accessing Azure through Visual Studio and a problem with Update 4. I'm not using Visual Studio just trying to connect through the browser.

One of our other developers can successfully login using the same userid/password. I tried a few things...rebooting and logging in immediately before opening any other apps...tried login from a virtual but same problem occurred every time.

The other developer mentioned it could have something to do with Office 365. I think this is the first time that I have tried to login since we installed Office 365 last week. I use a different userid for Office 365. So I tried my Office 365 userid and it successfully logged in to Azure. I then tried entering a dummy yahoo email as the userid as a test. This resulted in me being taken to the "Login Live" webpage. The login failed as expected (unkown userid). But I then tried my Azure userid on this page and it was successful logging in to Azure.

Can anyone suggest why I can't login through the Portal ? Is there some sort of a conflict between the Office 365 user and the Azure login ?

Anthony.

Comment: Is the email address that you were previously signing into Azure the same as your new Office 365 email address?

Comment: The email addresses are different.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario will arise if your previous account uses the same domain as is now hosted on Office 365.  The Azure Portal login page will do "home realm discovery" based on your email "bob@example.com" and if it finds an Azure AD instance (used for Office 365 auth) then you will be directed to the Azure AD login page.  If that email doesn't exist in Azure AD then the login will fail.

You should be able to use your Office 365 login to gain access though the username will need to be added as an Azure co-admin.

If you want to use your old account what you'll need to do in the Azure Portal login page is type "somethingrandom@hotmail.com" which will force you to the Microsoft Account login page.  On that page put your old email address and password and you should be able to login.

[I wrote a blog](http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2014/07/21/azure-admin-microsoft-and-organisational-account-access-after-federation/) about this sitation which may explain it better than the above.

Comment: Simon, (I'm the "other developer") I attempted to add the Office365 user ids as co-administrator and none of them were recognised as a Microsoft Account. The error message in Azure was:

`The co-administrator must be either a Microsoft Account or a user account in the Default Directory (lansacloudlansacom.onmicrosoft.com) directory.`

Comment: I searched a little further and found [manage-office365-windows-azure-active-directory](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/manage-office365-windows-azure-active-directory-waad-microsoft-account/). 

As we didn't set up Office 365 we do not know the tenant name as now we just use our normal domain name. The Office365 admin is also not available.

Can you confirm that we need the tenant name and not the email address that we think we are using?

Comment: Right, so your Office 365 AD isn't the one being used in your Azure subscription. If you follow my blog you should be able to login with your old Microsoft Account (MSA) instead. I'd then recommend you setup a new MSA and use that to log into your Azure environment.

Comment: I've found out the tenant name - mytenant.onmicrosoft.com. I can send test emails to my Office365 account myname@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com and also to myname.surname@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com.
My Office365 login is myname.surname@company.com.au
Neither of the mytenant names that work as email addresses are accepted as valid co-administrators in Azure. So is there a way to add some name that links Office and Azure or if that is not possible how do I  create another Azure subscription which links the two - which name or domain do I use for that?

Comment: Rob - you need to signup for Azure using the same Microsoft Account (Live ID) that was originally used to register your Office 365 tenant. See the steps covered here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/09/10/empower-your-office-365-subscription-identity-management-with-application-access-enhancements-for-windows-azure-ad.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing all the saved cookies on your computer first, then trying again?

Comment: Sam, I tried your suggestion. Deleted all history including Cookies from IE and Firefox. Now, if I chose the option "Work or school account" as I always have I now get the error "We don't recognize this user ID or password". I found that saying its a "Microsoft Account" (login.live.com) works (even though it is a work email account). The other developer does login using "Work or school account" using the same email address as me.